# ffmpeg batch script image+audio fix

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

Found here on stackoverflow but cannot get it work. What names i must give to sound files? ffmpeg batch script that combines multiple audio clips with one image > mp4

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.mp3) do (
  ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "default.jpg" -i "%%~nxF" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec mpeg4 -shortest "%%~nF.mp4" 
)
```

Comment: Remove the `~nx` and `~n`

Comment: great working. but how to increase speed ? cuz is x2.6. can I add :

'-c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p'

Comment: Sure. But remove current acodec and vcodec.

Comment: hmm thanks for help but still slow speed any improvement please? thanks again.

Comment: Show the complete console output from one encoding and I'll give you some suggestions.